# Making a program which will compress a sentence into unique words and positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, text-files

I am currently making a program in Python which will compress a user input sentence into a list of unique words and positions. For example the sentence "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY" will be compressed to "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU" and the positions will be "12345678913967845".

Then afterwards the original sentence can be recreated from these unique words and positions.

My problem is that I am currently stuck, I have the compressing section working, however I'm really not sure how to uncompress the sentence(s). I mean I know how to read the text file, but no idea how to recreate the original sentence through unique words and positions.

Here is my current code:

```
###This section will compress the sentence(s)###
        txt_file = open("User_sentences.txt","wt")
        user_sntnce = input(str("\nPlease enter the sentence(s) you would\nlike compressed.\n\n➜ "))
        user_sntnce_list = user_sntnce.split(" ")                     
        print(user_sntnce_list)

        for word in user_sntnce_list: 
            if word not in uq_words:
                uq_words.append(word)
        txt_file.write(str(uq_words) + "\n")

        for i in user_sntnce_list:
            positions = int(uq_words.index(i) + 1)
            index.append(positions)
            print(positions)
            print(i)
            txt_file.write(str(positions))
    txt_file.close()
###This section will DECOMPRESS the sentence(s)###
    if GuideChoice == "2":
        txt_file = open("User_sentences.txt","r")
        contents = txt_file.readline()
        words = eval(contents)
        print(words)
        txt_file.close()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify a few things please? Are you using Python 2 or 3? You shouldn't tag both! Where are you reading `positions` from? In what format? What does the penultimate line (`print(words)`) print?

Comment: Sorry! Gloin I am currently using python 3.1.5, and I want read the positions from the text file when I come to uncompress the sentences! Also the penultimate line prints for example, the cat sat on the mat
['the', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']
1
the
2
cat
3
sat
4
on
1
the
5

Answer (score 0):

You can split the sentence by space into a list, and then enumerate through that list and store the positions in a defaultdict, which will allow you to create a list of positions per word (also, you don't need to pass a space into split):

```
from collections import defaultdict

positions = defaultdict(list)
user_sentence = 'ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY'
sentence = user_sentence.split()
for position, word in enumerate(list(sentence), start=1):
    positions[word].append(position)
```

The result is:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'WHAT': [3, 11], 'ASK': [1, 10], 'COUNTRY': [5, 17], 'NOT': [2], 'CAN': [6, 13], 'FOR': [8, 15], 'DO': [7, 14], 'YOU': [9, 12], 'YOUR': [4, 16]})
```

Comment: I want to be able to extract the positions and unique words from the text file and store them in two separate lists in Python, then afterwards I want to be able to do something like: list1 = [] list 2 = [] list 3= [] then for i in list 2: list3.append(list1[i]). I'm not sure if you understand but it's extracting the positions and unique words from the text file and storing them in 2 separate variables which I don't know how to do?! @Vincenzzzochi